# cron jobs - can you query the environment to find out when a job is about to run next?

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron

I'd like to know if there's a way to find out when the next time a cron job will run - via a bash job.
Has anyone tried something like this?

I've been googling but I haven't found anything yet.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

Just some more details of what I'm after.
When I check crontab -l, see the following output:

```
lab-1:/etc/crontabs# crontab -l
# do daily/weekly/monthly maintenance
# min   hour    day     month   weekday command
*/15    *       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/15min
0       *       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/hourly
0       2       *       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/daily
0       3       *       *       6       run-parts /etc/periodic/weekly
0       5       1       *       *       run-parts /etc/periodic/monthly

#Ansible: Run every minute
* * * * * run-parts /etc/periodic/1min
```

What I need to know is not just that the 15 minute folder is "enabled" but if there's a way, I'd like to know that for example, 3 minutes from now, the job in the 15 minute folder will be triggered.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it fit exactly your needs, but you can translate `crontab` files in english, check [crontab2english](https://www.cpan.org/authors/id/S/SB/SBURKE/crontab2english_0.71.pl)

```
   Usage:
     % crontab2english [-f] files...
   Or:
     % cat files... | crontab2english

   If you do just this:
     % crontab2english
   then it's the same as crontab -l | crontab2english

   Example output:
   % crontab2english | less
   Setting env var MAILTO to hulahoops@polygon.int

   Command: (line 2)
     Run: /bin/csh -c 'perl ~/thang.pl | mail -s hujambo root'
     At: 8:10am on    the 15th of    every month

   Command: (line 5)
     Run: df -k
     At: 5:40am    every day

   Command: (line 7)
     Run: ls -l /tmp
     At: 6:50am    every Monday

   Or with the -f ("f" for filter) switch, it just adds comments
   to the input file:

   % crontab2english -f | less
   # My happy crontab file
   MAILTO=hulahoops@polygon.int
   10 8 15 * * /bin/csh -c 'perl ~/thang.pl | mail -s hujambo root'
   #>  At: 8:10am on    the 15th of    every month


   40 5 * * * df -k
   #>  At: 5:40am    every day

   50 6 * * 1 ls -l /tmp
   #>  At: 6:50am    every Monday
```

Comment: hm. i need something either in bash or python.